# My container has a correct date and timezone. But my tomcat is getting one hour more than I configured. How to fix wrong time in tomcat 9 container?

Tags: java, timezone, containers, tomcat9, java-opts

I am trying to make it run setenv.sh to load some JAVA_OPTS but is it not loading nothing. My Tomcat start a .war files using springboot for start my application.
The problem here is that it is not loading correct timezone on java and it is not loading JMX and Prometheus exporters.

Here is my docker file.

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
MAINTAINER Me

USER root

RUN rm -rf ${JAVA_HOME}/*src.zip

ENV JAVA_PKG=jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
ENV CATALINA_PKG=apache-tomcat-9.0.55.tar.gz

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_202
ENV CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8 
#RUN echo "America/Sao_Paulo" >  /etc/timezone
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

#ENV TZ America/Sao_Paulo
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8


COPY ./java/${JAVA_PKG} /opt/
RUN tar -xzvf /opt/${JAVA_PKG} --directory=/opt/
RUN rm /opt/${JAVA_PKG}

COPY ./tomcat/${CATALINA_PKG} /opt/
RUN tar -xzvf /opt/${CATALINA_PKG} --directory=/opt/
RUN rm /opt/${CATALINA_PKG}

ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

# Create a group and user
#RUN addgroup -S tomcat_grp && adduser -S tomcat -G tomcat_grp - criar UID 1002 para facilitar as permissões de escrita no host
RUN groupadd tomcat_grp && useradd -r -u 1002 tomcat -g tomcat_grp

COPY ./lib/* ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/

RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat_grp ${CATALINA_HOME}
RUN chmod -R 777 ${CATALINA_HOME}

RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat_grp ${JAVA_HOME}
RUN chmod -R 777 ${JAVA_HOME}

USER tomcat

EXPOSE 8080

USER root

#prometheus jmx exporter
RUN mkdir -p /opt/jmx_exporter
COPY ./tomcat/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar /opt/jmx_exporter
COPY ./tomcat/jmx_exporter/config.yaml /opt/jmx_exporter

#clean image
#CMD ["sh", "-c", "apt update"; "apt install wget -y"; "apt-get clean ; apt-get autoclean ; apt-get autoremove"]
RUN apt update && apt install wget -y; apt clean; apt autoclean; apt autoremove

#start tomcat
COPY startup.sh /usr/local/
CMD ["sh", "-c", "chmod a+x /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/bin/catalina.sh; chmod a+x /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/bin/setenv.sh; /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/bin/setenv.sh; chmod a+x /usr/local/startup.sh ; /usr/local/startup.sh"]
#RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/startup.sh ; /usr/local/startup.sh

#CMD ["sh", "-c", "chmod a+x ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/*.sh; chmod a+x /usr/local/startup.sh ; ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh"]

#COPY startup.sh /usr/local/
#CMD chmod a+x /usr/local/startup.sh 
# Launch Tomcat on startup
#CMD /usr/local/startup.sh
```

This is a one service of my compose stack:

```yaml
  tomcat2_ecops_reports_pabx:
    build: *build
    labels:
      - reports_pabx  
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: ecops_reports_pabx_${CLIENT_NAME}_${VER}_${IMAGE_TAG}
    restart: unless-stopped
#    command: *command    
    volumes:
      -  ${LOCALTIME}
      -  ${PABXREPTS_PRD}:${POD_WEBAPPS}
      -  ${REPORTS}:${POD_WEBAPPS}/reports
      -  ${CONF_CTXT}/context_reports.xml:${CONF_CTXT}/context.xml
#    environment:
#      CATALINA_OPTS: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP"
#      JAVA_OPTS: "-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml \
#        -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo" 
    ports:
      - 9912:8088 
      - 8192:8191
      - 9402:9404      
    networks: *networks
```

I got a correct time inside my container:

```
root@b2ad0fe2338b:/# date
qua 04 jan 2023 19:31:53 -03
root@b2ad0fe2338b:/#
```

I got correct time in my host system:

```
[root@VM-L-13104 projeto_psv]# date
Wed Jan  4 19:31:42 -03 2023
```

Time in probe:

> Current time: Wed Jan 04 20:31:35 BRST 2023

This is the springboot process:

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 2.52G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.331 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.vault.util.PropertySourceVault.init Keystore password should be either masked or prefixed with one of {EXT}, {EXTC}, {CMD}, {CMDC}
    org.apache.tomcat.vault.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: Keystore password should be either masked or prefixed with one of {EXT}, {EXTC}, {CMD}, {CMDC}
        at org.apache.tomcat.vault.security.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:168)
        at org.apache.tomcat.vault.util.PropertySourceVault.init(PropertySourceVault.java:105)
        at org.apache.tomcat.vault.util.PropertySourceVault.<init>(PropertySourceVault.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.<clinit>(Digester.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.parseServerXml(Catalina.java:608)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:709)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.55
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 10 2021 08:26:45 UTC
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.55.0
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1160.80.1.0.1.el7.x86_64
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/jdk1.8.0_202/jre
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_202-b08
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/conf/logging.properties
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dserver=tomcat
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djvm=tomcat
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.port=
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dajp.port=8119
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.685 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dssl.port=8443
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dshutdown.port=8115
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DjavaEncoding=UTF-8
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DUseSunHttpHandler=true
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8191
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8191
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/temp
04-Jan-2023 19:33:49.692 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
04-Jan-2023 19:33:50.555 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
04-Jan-2023 19:33:50.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1490] milliseconds
04-Jan-2023 19:33:50.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
04-Jan-2023 19:33:50.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
04-Jan-2023 19:33:50.780 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/webapps/probe.war]
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
04-Jan-2023 19:34:03.393 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/webapps/probe.war] has finished in [12,612] ms
04-Jan-2023 19:34:03.450 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/webapps/reports.war]
04-Jan-2023 19:34:04.725 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
04-Jan-2023 19:34:04.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55/webapps/reports.war] has finished in [1,281] ms
04-Jan-2023 19:34:04.743 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
04-Jan-2023 19:34:04.840 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [14195] milliseconds
```

This is a main part of my setenv.sh file:

```bash
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_202
TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55
SERVER_NAME=tomcat
HOST_IP=10.1.1.144

# Language
LANG=pt_BR

#Custom Ports
#HTTP_PORT=80
#AJP_PORT=8119
SSL_PORT=8443
SHUTDOWN_PORT=8115
JMX_PORT=8191


# JMX Opts
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP"

#Prometheus JMX Exporter
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml"

#SET TIMEZONE IN JVM
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"
```

How can I tell it to load correctly my setenv.sh file? Is this something on spring config lacking configurations?

I tried a lot of things to start it using my VARs even putting then into catalina.sh and I have no positive results.

I need to load those apps and load prometheus and JMX and put it to work with correct time. All my VARS are working on a real installed tomcat.

What I am doing wrong, please?

I would like to run my tomcat 9 servers with java loading a correct timezone. It is loading one hour more than current time. And I need to put JMX to be acessed outside my container. And I need to export this container status to Prometheus.

Answer (score 2):

## Rule change in Brazil time zone

Your problem seems to be that Java is reporting the same time, but in daylight saving time (I believe BRST=Brasilia Summer Time, which is UTC-2).

According to Wikipedia, [Brazil stopped using daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Brazil) in 2019. According to [this page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tzdata-versions.html) the change was included in Java 1.8.0_231, while you’re on Java 1.8.0_202.

Updating to Java 1.8.0_231 or later, if you can, ought to fix the inconsistency.

Comment: Amazing detective work here, well done.

Comment: You solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
MAINTAINER Me

USER root

RUN rm -rf ${JAVA_HOME}/*src.zip

ENV JAVA_PKG=jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
ENV CATALINA_PKG=apache-tomcat-9.0.55.tar.gz

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_202
ENV CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.55

# Set the timezone and locale
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8

# Install JDK and Tomcat
COPY ./java/${JAVA_PKG} /opt/
RUN tar -xzvf /opt/${JAVA_PKG} --directory=/opt/
RUN rm /opt/${JAVA_PKG}
COPY ./tomcat/${CATALINA_PKG} /opt/
RUN tar -xzvf /opt/${CATALINA_PKG} --directory=/opt/
RUN rm /opt/${CATALINA_PKG}
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="$CATALINA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

# Create a group and user
RUN groupadd tomcat_grp && useradd -r -u 1002 tomcat -g tomcat_grp

# Copy libs and set permissions
COPY ./lib/* ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/
RUN chown -R tomcat:tomcat_grp ${CATALINA_HOME}

 - 

To set environment variables in a Docker container, you can use the ENV instruction in your Dockerfile, like you have done. You can also set environment variables when you start the container using the -e flag with docker run.

For example: docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=UTC" my_image

To load

The environment use source command the docker file for example COPY setenv.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"] ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh && exec /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run"] . $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

environment: JAVA_OPTS: "-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo" CATALINA_OPTS: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP"

JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP

environment: JAVA_OPTS: ${JAVA_OPTS} CATALINA_OPTS: ${CATALINA_OPTS}

env_file:

./env_file.env
environment: JAVA_OPTS: "-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo" CATALINA_OPTS: "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP" JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9404:/opt/jmx_exporter/config.yaml -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP

environment: JAVA_OPTS: ${JAVA_OPTS} CATALINA_OPTS: ${CATALINA_OPTS}

env_file:

./env_file.env
----------
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you but I got the problem. If you look at this Dockerfile my partner copied an tomcat tar file to conteiner but I was adjusting a uncompressed setenv.sh outside. That's why it was getting nothing from modified setenv.sh. I fixed it adding an uncompressed directory that now I was doing my modifications.